# Why does gamescene.sks in my project close Xcode?

Tags: ios, ios10, gamekit

I have a project doing a game and it requires using `gamescene.sks`, whenever I hover / click on it it closes Xcode, I searched here, and tried some solutions it didn't work, by the way, I'm running OS X on VMware El Capitan.

Comment: Take a look at the discussion under this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912395/xcode-8-x-crashes-with-gamescene-sks-file), i hope they will help you.

This [discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/29021) may help you too.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed i tried it but it still doesn't work.