# Xcode9.X crashes when creating or opening "SKScene.sks" file

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene, xcode9.1

I know there is a similar post for this at [xCode 8.x crashes with "GameScene.sks" file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912395/xcode-8-x-crashes-with-gamescene-sks-file)
but this is for xcode 9. 
I am running high sierra 10.12 on VMware and every time I attempt to open, or to create a new GameScene xcode promptly crashes. But what is odd is the file is created, but not shown within xcode unless it is removed from the folder and added back, but not created. So I believe the issue is solely around opening the GameScene file

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but only when I select a Texture for a Sprite.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: currently I havn't found a work around for this