# Xcode 9.3 crashes when opening GameScene in VM

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, virtual-machine

So there have been a couple of other posts about this, but they're either for Xcode 8.x, not for VMs, or never received a satisfactory answer.

I'm trying to run SpriteKit and I'm having the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912395/xcode-8-x-crashes-with-gamescene-sks-file), where Xcode crashes immediately on selecting GameScene.sks. It seems to be a VM problem, because I can open the very same GameScene files just fine on my office Mac. I've went ahead and tried both VMWare and VirtualBox, both of which have the same result.

Other posts led me to believe it's something to do with drivers/virtualization regarding the GPU or acceleration. Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: You cannot open GameScene.sks file in any VM software. No means NO. there is no solution so far. If you want to make a game in SpriteKit, go for a MacBook or any other Mac PC. I was using VMware Workstation for about a year before buying a Mac. I was facing the same problem and did not get a remedy so far.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that may be the case. That's a real downer. Hopefully someone comes up with something eventually.